# Is there a performance difference between switch case and if elseif in Dart

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, dart

Lately I watched a video on YouTube about Unity and performance improvements.
In this Video was mentioned, that there is no real performance difference between extensive switch case structures or the same routine as if else structure. So everything came down to personal preferences and readability.

While this seems to be true for **C#**, I was wondering if the same is true for **Dart**.
Does anyone know and if why this is?

Or, maybe does anyone know how to benchmark something like that?

**Cheers!**

Comment: Jumptables can make switch cases faster in some scenarios but i don't think so they are measurable most of the time

Answer (score -1):

it is believed that in modern programming languages there is no difference between these constructs.

Comment: Actually it can be a false statement for C#, cause `switch` statements can be implemented as jump tables.

Comment: @GuruStron ok. [if we talking about "simple constructions"]